# How to link a segment to a bone to get a better result?

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm making a rig in blender, pretty simple one, the only problem right now is this:

[image]

You can see it's pretty messed up.
I want to get to this result:

[image]

So I think I need to rotate the loop cut in the middle of the arm, or something like that, but I want it to be automatic when I rotate the bone. Could anyone help me please? I've been stuck on this for 5 days. (No joke, I'm still a begginer, and everywhere I look, it's either for v2.7 and below, or they use a more complex rig and thus blender works fine.)

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4392vKZ5" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4392vKZ5/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply shearing the edge loop at the elbow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the weight painting a bit and enable the *Armature* modifier's *Preserve Volume* option, but it won't improve the thing a lot. What you can do though is create a new shape key and move up the arm fold's edge loop so that the arm bends the way you want, and if you don't want to manipulate the shape keys everytime you bend the forearm, I guess you need to create a driver.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Hum, that's a bit complicated for me, but as you said, I'd need to do that everytime I bend the arm. What is a driver though?

Comment: you can give the forearm bone a driver that will command the shapekey to activate each time you rotate it, so the only operation you'll have to do is rotate the forearm, watch some tutorials on youtube, I think it has been simplified: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WouPZqB4fo